# ffmpeg fails to detect subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, copy

Just encoding an episode of Game of Thrones, Season 5, Episode 6 - Unbowed Unbent Unbroken. First copy to a temporary file, and thats whats fails to detect all subtitles. Here is an example that works, but you'll see that most subtitles are only detected after the encoding starts - if you set those to be the subtitle copied - it just fails to detect. So how do I select the subtitles to copy, that are only found during the copy?

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -probesize 300M -analyzeduration 180M -i E6-UnbowedUnbentUnbroken.mpg -map 0:s:2 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c copy tmp2.mkv
```

Doah - can't post the full output - its detected as spam!

Comment: Try without `-fflags +genpts -probesize 300M -analyzeduration 180M`. It looks like you are assuming we have your input file `E6-UnbowedUnbentUnbroken.mpg`, and can just execute the command, and see the issue. Can we actually do that? Don't post the full output, only the relevant output... I think you need to use FFprobe to identify the subtitles before executing FFmpeg, but maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: Found my problem. the ```-fflags +genpts``` was to avoid ```[matroska @ 0x562af99b74c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 1. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[matroska @ 0x562af99b74c0] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
``` problem was the subtitles started after the scan region as so ```-probesize 3000M -analyzeduration 3000M``` solved the problem

Comment: @Summers if you solved it, please share an answer.