# Unexpected output when using FFMPEG to add multiple English Subtitles to MP4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4, subtitles

I am trying to soft-encode 3 subtitle files into my film.
I extracted the subtitles from the DVD using ByteCopy

I am using this command to add the files:

```
ffmpeg -i BloodDiamond.mp4 -i BLOODDIAMOND_1_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_6_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_8_English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:2 language=eng BloodDiamond_Subs.mp4
```

But I get this kind of errors in the output:

> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value
> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40]
> Application provided duration: -103001 / timestamp: 3405107000 is out of range for mov/mp4 format [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value
>
> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] Application provided duration: -857000 / timestamp: 3476787000 is out of range for mov/mp4 format [mp4 @000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value

is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Not an answer, not even an hint of an answer, just a comment with a suggestion: Use Handbrake instead.

Comment: It could be the same issue as described [here](https://superuser.com/q/1818832/635712). Try adding `-probesize 3000M -analyzeduration 3000M` (as commented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
fmpeg -i BloodDiamond.mp4 -i BLOODDIAMOND_1_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_6_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_8_English.srt \
      -filter_complex "[0:v:0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v];[0:a:0]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a]"  \
      -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 \
      -c:s mov_text \
      -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:2 language=eng \
      BloodDiamond_Subs.mp4
```

This will rewrite the timestamps. It may not work if something else is causing the problem.

Comment: Please can you give me more details about how that works?
Also, do I put that at the end of my statement:  `fmpeg -i BloodDiamond.mp4 -i BLOODDIAMOND_1_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_6_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_8_English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:2 language=eng BloodDiamond_Subs.mp4`

Comment: I have updated the command by hand. I have not tested it. 
PTS-STARTPTS rewrites the timestamps starting from zero.
`-c copy` will not work because the new command uses filters for audio and video, and you are re-encoding the subtitles for MP4 container.

If the timestamps error is caused by encryption, data corruption or missing data, rewriting timestamps will not work.